# Variable not being written to array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I am creating a simple 'bingo caller' tool. There will be a set of phrases in an array - I want to pick random phrases. However, once one is picked, I don't want it picked again.

At the moment - I'm just using random numbers (which will be used to pull the phrases from the array).

I have a function that generates the random number - based on the number of phrases in the function and then checks to see if it exists in an array of drawn numbers. If it doesn't - it is added if it does then the function stops (I want the function to run again - I was calling the function from within itself but it behaved erratically so I have simplified it to stop!).

The picked number is displayed as is the drawn number array too.

However, the function doesn't display how I'd expect it to: as soon as a duplicate number is arrived at, the code begins to add several elements to the array... I'm expecting it not to add anything if it's already there...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Teaching Styles Bingo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var words = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'Six'
    ];
    var drawn=[];

    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="getNum()">Click me</button>
    <p id="never">Hello</p>
      <p id="collection"></p>
        <p id="first"></p>
        <script  type="text/javascript">
       // random number -> make it x
       // then, check is it the first number? If so - add to array
       // if not, then check: is it already in the array? If so - stop the function
       // if not, add it to the array and wait for further instruction
       // output to document the number picked and the contents of the array so far.
        function getNum()
        {
         var x=(Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length)));
             var count=drawn.length;
            if (count<1)
                {
                drawn.push(x); 
                document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;  
                document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
                document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "First Number";
                }
            else
        {
            for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
               if (drawn[i] === x)
                   {
                       return;
                   }
                else
                {
                drawn.push(x); 
                document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;
                document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
                document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Not First Number";
                }
            }
        }   
       }
       </script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why doesn't the script simply add nothing if the value exists in the array? Why does the script add several numbers to the array at a time (or at least - the output to html make it look like it does!)

Comment: Do you wanna add empty value or nothing(`''`) if value already exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `drawn.push(x);` is put inside the for loop.

Everytime `drawn[i] === x` fails, it pushes `x` to the end of `drawn`. Then your `drawn` will end up with multiple `x`. Move your `drawn.push(x);` out of your for loop to prevent it.

Even better, use `indexOf()` to check if `x` is already in `drawn`

```
if (drawn.indexOf(x) === -1) {
    drawn.push(x);
}
```

Comment: `if (drawn.indexOf(x) !== -1) {` should be `if (drawn.indexOf(x) == -1) {`. Push the value into array only if not exists

Comment: Great - I wasn't aware of the indexOf function so much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Teaching Styles Bingo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var words = [
      'One',
      'Two',
      'Three',
      'Four',
      'Five',
      'Six'
    ];
    var drawn = [];
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="getNum()">Click me</button>
  <p id="never">Hello</p>
  <p id="collection"></p>
  <p id="first"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // random number -> make it x
     // then, check is it the first number? If so - add to array
     // if not, then check: is it already in the array? If so - stop the function
     // if not, add it to the array and wait for further instruction
     // output to document the number picked and the contents of the array so far.
    function getNum() {
      var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length)));
      console.log(x);

      var count = drawn.length;
      if (count < 1) {
        drawn.push(x);
        document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;
        document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "First Number";
      } else if (drawn.indexOf(x) == -1) {
        drawn.push(x);
        document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;
        document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Not First Number";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that it should first go through all the elements and check if `x` is there and push/ignore the element afterwards, i.e., to replace

```
        for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
           if (drawn[i] === x)
               {
                   return;
               }
            else
            {
            drawn.push(x); 
            document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;
            document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
            document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Not First Number";
            }
        }
```

with something like

```
        var is_present = false;
        for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
           if (drawn[i] === x)
               {
                   is_present=true;break;
               }
        }

            if(!is_present)
            {
            drawn.push(x); 
            document.getElementById("never").innerHTML = x;
            document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = drawn;
            document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Not First Number";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is when a phrase has been drawn, remove it from the **original** array and add it to the **drawn** array. This way, you don't even have to check if the phrase exists in the **drawn** array, since the **original** array will always contain phrases not drawn

```
var original = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
var drawn = []

function getIndex() {
  var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * original.length;
  return randX;
}

var index = getIndex();
var drawnWord = original[ index ];
// Remove the word from original array
original.splice(index, 1);
// Add word to drawn array
drawn.push( drawnWord );

// Then proceed to display your words
// ...
```